# Number of permutations of the word ABCDEFGHI which contains the string CDE; the strings AC and CF; the strings ABC and ECG

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

How many permutations of the letters ABCDEFGHI contain

---

a) the string CDE?

b) the strings AC and CF?

c) the strings ABC and ECG?

**Here is my solution:**

**a)** We treat the mentioned string as one single letter. Thus we have the possible letter A,B,CDE,F,G,H,I.

Then we have 7 letters of which we want to select 7 letters.

```
N=7

R=7

Permutation: P(7,7)=7!/(7-7)!

                   =7!=5040
```

**b)**   A string cannot contain both AC and CF, since the string

can only contain C once and C can not be followed by A and F.

Thus there are 0 string that contain both AC and CF.

**c)**  A string cannot contain both ABC and ECG, since the string

can only contain C once and C can not be followed by A and E.

Thus there are 0 string that contain both ABC and ECG.

---

**Is my solution right? or need any modification?**

Comment: The statement of part b) and its solution are in conflict.  Should it BE AC and CF or AC and FE?  a) and c) are correct.

Comment: it was mistake now i correct solution @saulspatz

Comment: Your solution is incorrect.  If the string contains the substring ACF, then it contains both AC and CF.  The C is *preceded* by A and followed by F.

Comment: How?like c)  if a string cannot contain both ABC & ECG . C cannot followed by A& E. Then how in question b) contains both AC & CF? @saulspatz

Comment: In part (b), you could have the string ACFBDEGHI, which is admissible since it contains the substring AC in the first two positions and the substring CF in the second two positions.

Comment: is it look like this.... AC,CF,B,D,E,F,G,H,I? @N.F. Taussing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As saulspatz indicated in the comments, your answers to parts (a) and (c) are correct.

In part (b), I think the source of your confusion is that you are assuming that AC and CF must be separate strings.  Since you only have one copy of each letter available, for the strings AC and CF to both appear, they must overlap, meaning the permutation must contain the string ACF.  Thus, the number of permutations of the letters ABCDEFGHI is the number of permutations which contain the string ACF.  Thus, we have seven objects to permute: ACF, B, D, E, G, H, I.  The seven objects can be permuted in $7! = 5040$ ways.